# Remove double quotes json created using toJSON

Tags: json, r, jsonlite

I use the function `toJSON` like this to create a json:

```
data<-toJSON(list("tablename"= unbox("test.csv"),
                  "header" = header_df,
                  "data" = test1
))
```

the result is the following:

data

```
{"tablename":"test.csv","header":["PassengerId","Pclass","Name","Sex","Age","SibSp","Parch","Ticket","Fare","Cabin","Embarked"],"data":[["892","3","Kelly, Mr. James","male","34.5","0","0","330911","7.8292","","Q"]]}
```

The problem is that it is adding double quotes for the `PassengerID` and the `Age` numbers. If I modify manually the JSON to this:

```
data<-'{"tablename":"test.csv","header":["PassengerId","Pclass","Name","Sex","Age","SibSp","Parch","Ticket","Fare","Cabin","Embarked"],"data":[[892,"3","Kelly, Mr. James","male",34.5,"0","0","330911","7.8292","","Q"]]}'
```

then it is working fine. How can I remove the double quotes of some elements in the JSON when creating the JSON?

You can find the input data here:

Hi, you can find it here [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/snr0jjmra9c4l8g/test.csv?dl=0) I use the following to load it

```
test <- read.csv("~/Titanic R/test.csv")
header_df<-names(test)
test<-test[1,]
test1<-as.matrix(test)
```

Comment: Please provide sample input data to pass to `toJSON()` in order to make your example [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: I updated the question you will have this information now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, part of the problem is that you are loosing the proper data classes when you do `as.matrix`; that converts everything to a character value. Then R no longer remembers what was numeric. It's best to avoid this step.

To get a result like the one you desire, you need an unnamed, unboxed mixed-type list. Here's an example with your data

```
test <- read.csv("~/../Downloads/test.csv", stringsAsFactors=F)

header_df<-names(test)
test<-test[1,]

library(jsonlite)
data<-toJSON(list("tablename"= unbox("test.csv"),
                  "header" = header_df,
                  "data" = Map(unbox, unname(as.list(test)))
))

data
# {"tablename":"test.csv","header":["PassengerId","Pclass","Name","Sex","Age","SibSp","Parch","Ticket","Fare","Cabin","Embarked"],"data":[892,3,"Kelly, Mr. James","male",34.5,0,0,"330911",7.8292,"","Q"]}
```

Based on your comment, if you have more than one row of data, this strategy should work (using `magtrittr` library to make things easier)

```
test <- read.csv("~/../Downloads/test.csv", stringsAsFactors=F)    
header_df<-names(test)

library(magrittr)
tomixedlist <- . %>% unname %>% lapply(unbox)
dx <- split(test, 1:nrow(test)) %>% lapply(tomixedlist) %>% unname

library(jsonlite)
data<-toJSON(list("tablename"= unbox("test.csv"),
                  "header" = header_df,
                  "data" = dx
))
```

Comment: Thanks that fix my problem with the data clasess but I did the matrix because I need this double `[[` after the data because I have multiple records. `data":[[` ...

Otherwise the service that I am calling doesn't accept my json.

Comment: I've added a new example that should work in that case.